# Using buzzer without delay [C] STM32

Tags: c, stm32

i using interruptcounter from STM32 to count a rotating speed of fan. 
On the beginning of counting - I give a buzzer tone with:

```
void Beep(int ton) {
    uint16_t i = 0;
    do {
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_4);
        Delay(ton);
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_4);
        Delay(ton);
        i++;
    } while (i < 50);
}
```

of course of delay interruptconter get more counts. How can realize a buzzer without using Delay function?

```
// Start beep, begin measurement
        if (sec_cnt == 3 && measuring == TRUE) {
//          Beep(5000);
            }

        // Stop beep, measurement done
        if (sec_cnt == timer + 3 && measuring == TRUE) {
//          Beep(4000);
        }
```

Comment: Use on-chip hardware timers or PWM.

Comment: Hmm, what is wrong: I maked two Timer: TIM8 and TIM 2 -> TIM8 is a second timer for delay, TIM 2 is a PWM Timer for Buzzer, but buzzer make a noice all time: `void Beep(uint32_t signal) {
 uint16_t beep_sec_cnt = 0;
 TIM2->CCR1 = signal;
 if (TIM_GetFlagStatus(TIM8, TIM_FLAG_Update) == SET) {
    beep_sec_cnt++;
    TIM_ClearFlag(TIM8, TIM_FLAG_Update);
 }
 if(beep_sec_cnt>=1) {
  TIM2->CCR1 = 0;
 }
}`